# How to import a list of lists (of integers) from text file and treat them mathematically?

Tags: python, string, split, python-import, readlines

I have data in text.txt file

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
[[10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15], [16, 17, 18]]
```

and so on
I want to read each line of the text file and treat them as integers e.g. plot these points in 3d space. When I import the file by

```
with open('text.txt') as f:
    content = f.readlines()
    for x in content:
        print(x)
```

it takes it as:

```
'[','[','1' etc...
```

So I am confused what to use as separator for split() function. Will appreciate some suggestions.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built in function [eval()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) to interpret python lists from files:

```
with open('file.txt') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        pylist = eval(line)
        print(pylist)
```

If you are not 100% sure about the nature of this file or if it would contain data that another user manually generated, as pointed out by @G_M, you should use [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) that will only evaluate a python literal:

```
import ast

with open('file.txt') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        pylist = ast.literal_eval(line)
        print(pylist)
```